# Error 400 with PATCH method using PHP stream_context_create function to pass JSON data to API

Tags: php, json, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to post to this [Microsoft API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/597029932bcd590e74b648fb/operations/5970428523618c05e45ab128) but I'm getting an Error 400. Works fine when using their browser-based API test console and in Postman but I can't get it working using my PHP code below. Where am I going wrong?

```
  $myObj->update->name = "API test";
  $myObj->update->qnaList->qnaId = "331";
  $myObj->update->qnaList->answer = "I have been updated";
  $myObj->update->qnaList->source = "Editorial";
  $myObj->update->qnaList->questions->add = "What is your name";
  $myObj->update->qnaList->metadata->add->name = "category";
  $myObj->update->qnaList->metadata->add->value = "personality";
  $data = json_encode($myObj);

  $url = '[https://apiurl]';
  $options = array(
    'http' => array(
    'method'  => 'PATCH',
    'content' => $data,
    'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                       "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: [mykey]"
    )
  );
  $context    = stream_context_create($options);
  $result     = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
  $response   = json_decode($result, true);
  print_r($response);
```

Comment: API documentation here: https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v3.0/knowledgebases/{knowledgeBaseID}

Not sure what you mean by definition of $myObj. This variable is used to construct my JSON data before encoding to pass through the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are problems with the JSON body you are trying to send.

This works for me and returns 204:

```
<?php

$myObj->update->name = "API test";
$myObj->update->qnaList = array();
$myObj->update->qnaList[0]->qnaId = "1";
$myObj->update->qnaList[0]->answer = "I have been updated";
$myObj->update->qnaList[0]->source = "Editorial";
$myObj->update->qnaList[0]->questions->add = array();
$myObj->update->qnaList[0]->questions->add[0] = "What is your name";
$myObj->update->qnaList[0]->metadata->add = array();
$myObj->update->qnaList[0]->metadata->add[0]->name = "category";
$myObj->update->qnaList[0]->metadata->add[0]->value = "personality";
$data = json_encode($myObj);

$kbid = "<YOUR-KB-ID>";

$url = 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v3.0/knowledgebases/' . $kbid;
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'ignore_errors' => true,
        'method' => 'PATCH',
        'content' => $data,
        'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <YOUR-KEY>\r\n"
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$response = json_decode($result, true);

echo $response . "\r\n";
?>
```